# How to rollback metadata changes using Jenkins and bash script

Tags: community, deployment, ant, jenkins, rollback

I am working on a project in which I have to rollback the metadata components which we have deployed into destination org using Jenkins. Does anyone have built this kind of project / Scenario.

**Steps I am following:**

1. While deploying metadata components, I am creating its backup using
   Jenkins.

   2. If we want to rollback our changes we are going to our repository and comparing old version of git with the latest changes which were
      deployed.
   3. After comparing the bash script will find the different and create destructivechanges.xml file using ant.

I am not sure if that is my correct approach. We don't want to use external available tools in the market like Gearset, flosum etc.

Comment: This, in theory, seems possible but might involve a large amount of dev work required which is a  labor cost, getting a gearset or any other product might end up being 10 times cheaper